# Consecutive numbers where their revers numbers are primes

Tags: number-theory

Consider the consequtive numbers 1393 and 1394, when we revers their digits we get 3931 and 4931 which are  both prime numbers. Is this a well known property?

Here is my concerns:

Is there an infinite number of this numbers?

Let $k\geq 2$, for what values of $k$ there is $k$ consequtive numbers such that when we revers their digits we get prime numbers?

Any hint  or references would be helpful.

Comment: What base are you using?

Comment: @barakmanos ten.

Comment: Why? Is the base any more special than other bases?

Comment: @barakmanos ofcourse, consider this question in base two.

Comment: That would make base $2$ special (as no such consecutive numbers exist in this base). But it doesn't make base $10$ more special than any other (non-binary) base. Perhaps you should refine your question for the general case of base $N$ and $k=N-1$.

Comment: There are lots of examples in base $2$, assuming you don't mind leading $0$'s in the reversed numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that we have three consecutive numbers, then one of these numbers would have sum of digits divisible by $3$. Its reverse number would also be divisible by $3$, hence not prime. So $k=2$.

Comment: Unless the first number is $3 \times 10^k$ where $10^k + 3$ and $2 \times 10^k + 3$ are both prime: it's true for $k = 1, 5, 6, 17$.

Answer (score 1):

Heuristically we should expect infinitely many for $k=2$.  If $x$ does not end in $0$ or $9$ (so its reverse and that of $x+1$ have the same number of digits) and $x \equiv 1 \mod 3$, the probability that the reverses of $x$ and of $x+1$ are both prime should be on the order of $1/(\log x)^2$, and 
$\sum_x 1/(\log x)^2 = \infty$.  In fact these numbers should have roughly similar order of abundance to twin primes.
I found $1955$ examples below $10^5$ and $12943$ below $10^6$ (compare to $1224$ and $8169$ sets of twin primes in the same intervals).

I'm surprised the OEIS doesn't seem to have the sequence of $n$ such that the reversals of $n$ and $n+1$ are primes ($2,13,16,30,31,34,37,70,\ldots$).  Well, maybe it will soon...

EDIT: Now it does: [A257636](https://oeis.org/A257636)

Comment: Great ! Thanks also for the OEIS entry.